# Is there a way to "refresh" Outlook's Preview Pane?

Tags: vba, outlook

Based on a certain set of conditions (keywords in an email body), I programmatically make a setting change. This is done in my SelectionChange event trap.  But what I've noticed is that the change is not automatically reflected in the message in the Preview Pane. So, is there a way to "refresh" the display? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is remove the message from selection and then add it back:

```
set Msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Application.ActiveExplorer.RemoveFromSelection(Msg)
Application.ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection(Msg)
```